# How to ListView OnFocusChangeListener on array list items xml

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onfocus, onfocuschangelistener

Hello guys please help a Noob here that is just starting learn android.
Basically I have an activity that have TextView and on every Textview I set onfocusListener and everything is working perfect.
here is the code for the layout example country UK

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50.0dip"
        android:background="@drawable/button5_background">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="104dp"
            android:id="@+id/afrflag"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ukflag" />
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/custom_selector"
            android:id="@+id/uk"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:text="@string/uk"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18.0sp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

here the code OnFocusChangeListener for UK

```
TextView btnuk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uk);
    btnuk.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (hasFocus) {
                videoList.clear();
                fetchVideouk();
            }
        }

    });
```

so I decide to play around and make arrays.xml and put all the countries there and go try listview instead of TextView that I had to create so many lines acting as buttons.

here is my array.xml

```
    <string-array
        name="countryView">
        <item>@string/uk</item>
        <item>@string/frn</item>
        <item>@string/ita</item>
        <item>@string/ger</item>

    </string-array>
</resources>
```

and the xml for listview

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_selector">

        <ListView
            android:background="@drawable/button5_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/country_names"
            android:entries="@array/countryView"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

with the above code I see the country names load on my view but I dont know how to set onfocus on every item (country)

```
ListView listView;
    String[] uk;


    uk = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countryView);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.country_names);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, uk);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    listView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (hasFocus) {
                videoList.clear();
                fetchVideosuk();
            }
        }

    });
```

How do I set the onfocus for the next item then? example ger,Ita,etc I am sure this is not correct but I dont understand how?

Comment: Can you please put some screenshot defining what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an Custom Adapter for this.

**row_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] values){
        super(context, R.layout.row_layout, values);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(getItem(position));

        return view;
    }
}
```

You can do this by the following code in MainActivty.java:

```
uk = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countryView);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.country_names);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new MyAdapter(this, uk);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

for (int i=0; i<listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                // do something //
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but why edit text I asked for listview and on focus not on click also can you show an example please of on focus for uk and ger so i can understand how it works, I dont have problem when I make the list as textView but its a list coming from array xml please look at my code and sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: Dear thanks for the reply again just pasted and followed your steps but you interduced edittext here which is giving me new error as i dont have any edittext also can you show an example for the next on focus item example ger and frn (only ) no need on click here and without editText please.

Comment: Hi there I also want to say that all my job is  public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (hasFocus) {
                videoList.clear();
                fetchVideosuk();
            }
        }  so i dont use editText or onclick here its just fetching videolist sorry for the mis understood but I'am still a beginner.

Comment: anyone knows how simply apply onfocus to every item in my listview coming from string-array?

Comment: Sorry. Make that editText to textView. Typo error. I'm updating the code.

Comment: Hi there Thank you again but I already tried that and I had error so since I am not good at android I cant even explain what it is, can you please explain what value will you get with the above example? I real need to know how would I go to set all the list-array onfocuschangeListener and not onclick listener ? I have managed to make only 1 item onfocuschangeListener but dont know what to type for the next item and apply the onfocuse

Comment: Hey I'am updating an alternate. Please try that and let me know if it is working.

Comment: Hi Harv thanks for the reply but nothing is happening on focus, you think adapter problem? I used my code on the first post and its fetching the video, but not sure how to do for next list item foced. You helped a lot and I really thank you for this, I may just leave it as textView since its working, but I dont know how to keep the state focused when drawer is open, drawer goes back to first item, the reason I needed ListView is because you can cacheColorHint or ScrollingCache and when drawer is open again stays on the same item focused last. How can I do this for Textview? Please help me sir.

Comment: Hey try to change the Adapter Type to 'ListAdapter' instead of 'ArrayAdapter<String>'. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hi sorry Noob here how do I do that? I imported import android.widget.ListAdapter; and changed from ArrayAdapter to ListAdapter and its red line , also changed and imported that in myAdapter but still red.

Comment: rremove '<String>' part too.

Comment: Yes did that and the error disappeared, but its not fetching video on focus just focused and nothing happened. I didnt change anything on the Myadapter

Comment: How can I apply the textView I want always focused on first drawer opens? or last selected before closed, Basically my app have a drawer open on click, the drawer have list of videos on the right and name of the country on the left, when drawer close it goes back to first item on the left (country ) always how can I make the focus stay on the right  (video List ) so user can continue scroll and it will solve my issue. Many thanks sir.

Comment: Sorry the right pan is listview and TextView on the right, when drawer is open make it focused on the video list. Issue I have now is when I open drawer it focus by default on the first Item on the left ( because its not listView I cant set cachecolorHint or remember the last focused, I wanted to change this behavior, so I want to remember last focused ( when drawer is open for TextView).